# redraw bug on iPad while dragging objects

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

[Can someone tell me how to fix this problem or what the reason why this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iqn7.jpg)

Comment: If you are drawing a layer, the view that it is backing may need to have the clearsContextBeforeDrawing property set to true

Comment: thank you! I will try it.But what is interesting its only happens on ipad, on android and windows devices there is no such problem

Comment: Just let me know I'm very curious to find out if that was the culprit :)

Comment: The problem was in drop-shadow css property)